# How to correctly use loss function in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am testing a loss function to reduce both MSE and Cross_Entropy at the same time. I defined a loss function, but it seems that the loss is not going down. I am new to the deep learning area, any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

x1=np.random.uniform(0,100, 1000)
x2=np.random.uniform(-20,20, 1000)
y1= [int(i) for i in x1 % 3]
y2= x1*1.5 + np.random.randn(1000)
y3= 2*x1*x1 + np.random.randn(1000)
y4= x1*2.5 -10 +np.random.randn(1000)
y5=x1*2.5 +10 +np.random.randn(1000)

xs=np.array([x1,x2]).T
y1s= np.array(y1).reshape(-1,1)
y2s= np.array([y2,y3, y4, y5]).T
y1s=to_categorical(y1s)
scaler= MinMaxScaler()
xs_normed=scaler.fit_transform(xs)

from keras.layers import Dense, Input, Concatenate, Lambda
from keras.models import Model
from keras.losses import mse, categorical_crossentropy
import keras.backend as K

def loss_fun(real,pred, alpha=1, beta=1):

    c1_pred=pred[0]
    c1_real=real[0]
    c2_pred=pred[1]
    c2_real=real[1]
    loss1=mse(c2_real, c2_pred)
    loss2=categorical_crossentropy(c1_real, c1_pred)
    loss=K.sum(alpha*loss1 + beta*loss2)
    return loss

inputs= Input(shape=(2,))
d1=Dense(256, activation='relu')(inputs)
d2=Dense(256, activation='relu')(d1)
d3=Dense(3, activation='softmax')(d2)
d5=Dense(256)(d2)
d6=Dense(4)(d5)
model= Model(inputs=inputs, outputs= [d3, d6])
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=loss_fun)

model.fit(x=xs_normed, y= [y1s, y2s], batch_size=128, epochs=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is nothing wrong to use a loss function like you defined.

But I hope you use this loss function because you understand what you are going to optimize. Your loss function will jointly optimize your model on the euclidean and angular metric spaces.

The reasons why your model does not learn might due to

1. your alpha and beta values might need adjustment, it will be better for you try different combinations, e.g. any paired values from the list [1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,1].
2. your problem maybe inappropriate to this loss, especially when your target is not an one-hot encoded vector.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comments. I captured the error of one-hot encoding.. I added to_categorical() make it to one-hot..  Also, I added the sample size..
Now: loss for y2s becomes much small, but y1s still not change, even if I give it a large weight [1000, 1]. I suspect it is because of the mod function that is very unlinear, so it cannot learn? But deep learning, my understanding is that it can simulate any kind of function. I added two layers , the loss still not change.. any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use:

```
model.compile(loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'mse'], 
              loss_weights = [beta, alpha], ...)
```

If this doesn't work, the problem is not your loss.